# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/engine/http/ServerCall

Tags: java, json, servlets, restlet-2.0

I am trying to write a web service in Restlet and i have included jars listed below;
     1. json-simple-1.1
    2. log4j-1.2.16
      3. org.json-20120521
     4. org.restlet.ext.fileupload
    5. org.restlet.ext.json
      6. org.restlet.ext.servlet
     7. org.restlet.ext.xml
     8. org.restlet
    9. servlet-api

when i run this web services in tomcat 6 and hit the url into browser i get exception telling that:

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class       
    org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protoc        ol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
   root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/restlet/engine/http/ServerCall
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

root cause

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.restlet.engine.http.ServerCall
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)




 Even though the jar is present and my web.xml code as follows:

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"       
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>RestletDemo</display-name>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.aris.demo.application.RestletApplication</param-alue>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>




 </web-app>
```

Please help me..
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 6):

I guess I have caught your problem.

You went to restlet site and downloaded the restlet distribution as it comes in the page.
Now you need to revisit the site again and you will see you have downloaded default J2SE version of Restlet distribution.

Please choose second option J2EE from the drop-down and download.

Now you will get everything including `org.restlet.jar` and `org.restlet.ext.servlet.jar` you look for.

Place `WEB-INF lib`, restart server and life is happy now.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you copy the jar files to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the web application project.